# UIPickerview selection updates labels and next pickerview selections in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

longtime listener first time caller ;-) First post so go easy on me, if I haven't done the right thing I apologise in advance.  I am best described as a "plodder" when it comes to coding, but I enjoy it.  I am working on an app that displays sections of a whs act using picker views.  I can get the first picker to update the labels and the contents of the second picker, but I cannot get any data from the second picker no matter what I try.  The act consists of sections, subsections, paragraphs and subparagraphs...not all sections have the same number of subsections etc.

Code below:
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,  UIPickerViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var sectionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sectionNumberLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var subSectionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subSectionNumberLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var paragraphLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var paragraphNumberLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var subParagraphLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subParagraphNumberLabel: UILabel!

var sections = ["","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
var subSections = ["","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
var paragraphs = ["","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
var subParagraphs = ["","i","ii","iii","iv","v","vi","vii","viii","ix","x","xi","xii","xiii","xiv","xv"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    
    picker1.delegate = self
    picker1.dataSource = self

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    
    if component == 0 {
        return sections.count
    } else if component == 1 {
        return subSections.count
    } else if component == 2 {
        return paragraphs.count
    } else if component == 3 {
        return subParagraphs.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    
    if component == 0 {
        return String(sections[row])
    } else if component == 1 {
        return String(subSections[row])
    } else if component == 2 {
        return String(paragraphs[row])
    } else if component == 3 {
        return String(subParagraphs[row])
    } else {
        return ""
    }
    
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    
    if component == 0 {
        
        let str = sections[row]
        
        if str == "5" {
            sectionNumberLabel.text = "5"
            subSections = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
            sectionLabel.text = "Meaning of a person conducting a business or undertaking"
            subSectionNumberLabel.text = "1"
            subSectionLabel.text = "For this Act, a person conducts a business or undertaking -"
        }
        else if str == "6" {
            sectionNumberLabel.text = "6"
            subSections = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
            sectionLabel.text = "Meaning of a supply"
            subSectionNumberLabel.text = "1"
            subSectionLabel.text = "A supply of a thing includes a supply and resupply of the thing by the way of sale, exchange, lease, hire or hire-purchase, whether as a principle or agent"
        }
        else if str == "7" {
            sectionNumberLabel.text = "7"
            subSections = ["1","2","3"]
            sectionLabel.text = "Meaning of a worker"
            subSectionNumberLabel.text = "1"
            subSectionLabel.text = "A person is a worker if the person carries out work in any capacity for a person conducting a business or undertaking, including work as:"
        }
```

**I REMOVED CODE FROM HERE SO THE POST ISNT SO BIG**

```
        else {
            
            subSections = [""]
            sectionLabel.text = ""
            sectionNumberLabel.text = ""
            subSectionLabel.text = ""
            subSectionNumberLabel.text = ""
            paragraphLabel.text = ""
            paragraphNumberLabel.text = ""
            subParagraphLabel.text = ""
            subParagraphNumberLabel.text = ""
        }

        picker1.reloadAllComponents()
     
    }
    
}
```

}

The second picker displays the correct number of subsections, but when I move that picker nothing updates...my question is: how do I get information from the second picker, third picker and fourth picker?  Any advice appreciated, or directions to relevant tutorials etc....happy new year, Brett.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi BrettR and welcome to our community! Let's make some things clear to you.

1. You have created **one picker** with **4 components**.
2. Components in picker are the different columns that you see and the user can scroll vertically in order to choose one of the available options.
3. In order to identify which on of your components was updated you should use the **component parameter** of the delegate method `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`

So your code should look like that:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print("row: \(row) of: ")
        switch component {
        case 0:
            print("first component")
        case 1:
            print("second component")
        case 2:
            print("third component")
        case 3:
            print("fourht component")
        default:
            print("unhandling compoment")
        }
        print("selected\n")
    }
```

I also suggest to you to spend some time following/reading this tutorial https://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/ is extremely useful and to the point.

Comment: Hi kstefanou...thank you.  I have made the changes and will have a look at the tutorial.  Appreciate the time you spent responding...hope your new years was enjoyable, and safe!

Comment: Thanks BrettR for the wishes, wish you the best too. Please mark my answer the accepted in order to help more people find the correct answer with the same question like you. Good luck 